# How to check for orientation on starting Windows Phone 8 App?

Tags: windows-phone-8, orientation, landscape-portrait

I wonder how I can check for current orientation directly on startup (MainPage LoadedEvent).

Following code does not work:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;

    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(Orientation);
         if (Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape || Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
             Debug.WriteLine("Simulator and Device won't jump in here on startup (always PortraitUp)...");
    }
```

Why does it behave this way? And where can I get orientation correctly?

(I have enabled `SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"` and the app is shown in landscape view directly from the beginning.)

Ps.: Of course device and simulator are in landscape on startup ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add Orientation property?

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Orientation.MainPage"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Landscape"
    >
```

Comment: This seems to be the deal. I added (as mentioned above) `SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"`- In contrast to your example I have `Orientation="Portrait"`. If I change that to Landscape, I have the opposite problem always showing the orientation landscape. - Somehow I can understand this behaviour, because it is the default location, but I still wonder how can I solve my problem? Maybe with a different approach?

Right now I think registering the orientationChanged event might be enough. But is there another way?

Comment: Did subscribing to OrientationChanged event help you?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Lots of things going on here atm.
`OrientationChanged="MainPage_OnOrientationChanged"` Event subscription (basically) works. But if I want to ensure that it only occurs once on page navigation I have to add nasty global bool.
I'd really like to have this done in the constructor. But I assume there is no chance then? :/

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem: you wants to check the page orientation every time when the page was changed (navigated to other) or you wants to check the orientation only once on startup?

Comment: I don't think it does matter. But in my case I want to check every time the user navigates to the page (It's the MainPage, so also once on startup).

The result of my tries was, that the Orientation always matches the one you specified in XAML as standard in Constructor, Loaded-Event and OnNavigatedTo.
Nevertheless, if the device is in the opposite position, it triggers the OnOrientationChanged. So there the logic _can_ be done.

I was just hoping not needing to have that global variable to indicate whether it was the first orientationChanged.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fapps%2Fjj207002%2528v%3Dvs.105%2529.aspx&ei=i95SVeCDG8XJuASUwYGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGC1xSQUv7Ge6t0hbGP0hfdV8dYtw

Hope this is what you are searching

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{

if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
{
    // if portrait
}

else
{
   // If landscape
}
}
```

in your following xaml code :

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Orientation.MainPage"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Landscape"
>
```

include OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged"

```
     <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
              x:Class="Orientation.MainPage"
                SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"                  
                OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged"
        >
```